# Leaderboard for sum of points / number of games

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I've got stat model :

```
Stat(id: integer, points: float, user_id: integer, match_id: integer, team_id: integer)
```

For match model:

```
 Match(id: integer, team_a_id: integer, team_b_id: integer)
```

Stat can be duplicate with same `user_id` and `match_id`. What I need is to get the `SUM` of points for each `user_id` then divide it to number of `match_id` which is games played.

Example:

```
{id: 1, points: 2, user_id: 1, match_id: 1, team_id: 1}
{id: 2, points: 3, user_id: 1, match_id: 1, team_id: 1}
{id: 3, points: 4, user_id: 1, match_id: 2, team_id: 1}
```

So here I got 2 game. I need to get the sum of points of `user_id` then divide it to number of his game which is 2 (match_id 1 and 2). Then get the top 10 highest pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can further refine the query, but this should work joining User and Stat ang grouping by user_id.

In controller:

```
@users = User.joins(:match_stats)
             .group('users.id')
             .select("users.name AS name, SUM(match_stats.points) as tot_points, COUNT(DISTINCT match_stats.match_id) AS tot_matches, (SUM(match_stats.points)/COUNT(DISTINCT match_stats.match_id)) AS average_points_per_match")
             .order("average_points_per_match DESC")
             .limit(10)
```

And in view (very basic):

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <p><%= user.name %> | <%= user.tot_points %> | <%= user.tot_matches %> | <%= user.average_points_per_match %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum of a user's points from all their stats:

```
user_sum_points = user.stats.map(&:points).compact.sum
```

I'm not quite sure what second number you are asking for. Are you planning to divide by the total number of matches a user has played? If so, then you can count the unique ids of their matches:

```
user_num_matches = user.stats.map(&:match_id).uniq.length
```

Finally, do the division:

```
(user_sum_points / user_num_matches) unless user_num_matches == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

my old code:

```
stat= section
    .group(:user_id)
    .select("user_id, count(*) as matches_count, sum(points) as score")
    .where.not(match_id: nil)
```

turn to this:

```
stat= section
    .group(:user_id)
    .select("user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT match_id) as matches_count, sum(points) as score")
    .where.not(match_id: nil)
```

Fixed this by using `COUNT(DISTINCT match_id)` instead of `COUNT(*)`. Thanks! Credit to: @Ovidiu Toma